# c# class to xml attribute name with numbers

Tags: c#, xml, class, xml-serialization

I am trying to XmlSerializer a class in c#.

When my XML tags are

```
 <Identificadores>
                  <IdMensaje>123</IdMensaje>
                  <IdMensajeAnterior >123</IdMensajeAnterior>
                  <IdOperacion >123</IdOperacion>
```

Is simple, having a Indentificadores class name al properties with tag

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Identificadores")]
    public partial class Indetifiers
{

 [XmlElement(ElementName = IdMensaje")]
  public string AAA{ get; set; }
 [XmlElement(ElementName = IdMensajeAnterior")]
  public string BBB{ get; set; }
 [XmlElement(ElementName = IdOperacion")]
  public string CCC{ get; set; }
}
```

The problem I have is when XML tags has simbols or numbers...

```
 <_01:Identificadores>
                      <_01:IdMensaje>123</_01:IdMensaje>
                      <_01:IdMensajeAnterior >123</_01:IdMensajeAnterior>
                      <_01:IdOperacion >123</_01:IdOperacion>
 </_01:Identificadores>
```

I can not use ElementName with prefix `_01:`

There was an error reflecting type  `Identificadores`

I have `XML serialize` error

Is there a way to use nomber and symbols to create those tags from a class?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx

The numbers you're referring to in your example are actually namespace aliases. So when you define your serialization/deserialization attributes you need to specify the namespaces prefixes in order to avoid XML serialization errors.

As I mentioned, please have a look at the link above to understand better how XML namespaces work.

Comment: Thanks... you mean that I has to set namespace XML attribute to the class Property? or the method I use to serealized the class?

Comment: You can do it both ways. You can declare the namespace using an attribute at the class level, or you can pass the namespace using the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` class to the `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` method. Using the attribute is less flexible, meaning the namespace will always be present when serializing objects, where as passing it to the `XmlSerializer.Serialize()` method allows you to control whether you want the namespace or not in the output.